# Reduce numpy array in a smaller area

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpyArray with 2 point X and Y an example :

```
[[ 36.0142    -9.446138]
 [ 36.0142    -9.444951]
 [ 36.0142    -9.443764]
 ...,
 [ 43.565044   3.384145]
 [ 43.565044   3.385332]
 [ 43.565044   3.385893]]
```

I would like to reduce that area, passing a few points and obtaining the points that remain within the new area.

For example:

[image: all area]
[image: reduce area]
but remember... I have numpyArray, not matrix.

update---
a ok sorry.
the list are coods.
i hav this code to generate Latitude and Altitude:

```
arrayX = list()
    arrayX.append(str(x1))
    while x1 < x2:
        x1 = x1 + space
        arrayX.append(str(x1))
    arrayX.append(str(x2))
    tam = len(arrayX)-1
    if arrayX[tam] < arrayX[tam-1]:
        del arrayX[-2]
        tam = tam-1
    if arrayX[tam] == arrayX[tam-1]:
        del arrayX[-1]
    arrayX = map(float, arrayX)
    return(arrayX)
```

example

```
xpts[1,2,3,4]
ypts[6,7,8]
```

then i use.

```
Points = np.array(list(itertools.product(Xpts, Ypts)))

points[[1,6],[1,7][1,8][2,6],[2,7][2,8]......[4,8]]
```

Comment: Please explain more on what the "area" means in relation to the input array. Also, how/where are the points from `..passing a few points ` defined/listed?

Comment: Looks like you should be using Geopandas.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/217578/1639625